# Sharepoint List, users only view their own Items

Tags: list, sharepoint, permissions, items

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 and I have a list where I want users to only be able to see their own list items. I have already gone into the advanced list settings and set Item-level permissions so they could only read their own items, but it doesn't work.

The users are set to contribute permissions.

Thanks for the help!
Ethan

Comment: Oh, also, I want people with full access to be able to view all of the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out. There was nothing wrong with what I had, but under the server administration panel, all users had full read audit, or something like that so they had full read of the content no matter what the rest of the permissions where.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by Item-level Permissions

See this blog post for further details, http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=58